# c# array function argument pass one dimension

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, .net-3.5

Let say I got this function :

```
void int Calculate(double[] array) {}
```

And in my main I got this array:

```
double[,] myArray = new double[3,3];
```

How can I call Calculate(...) ?

I try (that's don't compile) :

```
double[] mySingleArray = myArray[0];
```

What I want to avoid is unnecessary loop (for).

I declare a regular array, but if a jagged array or any other type of array works better, it's fine for me.

I use c# 3.5

Comment: I'm curious to know what your calculate method does.  I bet we could do it as a lambda expression use an IEnumerable aggregate extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's declare your Calculate() method like this:

```
int Calculate(IEnumerable<double> doubles)
```

Don't worry, you can still pass an array to that code.  You might also need `IList<double>`, but 9 times out of 10 the IEnumerable is good enough.  The main thing is that this will let us use the `yield` keyword to slice up your array in an efficient way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Slice(this T[,] values)
{
    return Slice(values, 0, 0);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Slice(this T[,] values, int index)
{
    return Slice(values, 0, index);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Slice(this T[,] values, int dimension, int index)
{
    int length = values.GetUpperBound(dimension);
    int[] point = new int[values.Rank];
    point[dimension] = index;
    dimension = 1 - dimension;// only works for rank == 2
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        point[dimension] = i;
         yield return (T)values.GetValue(point);
    }
}
```

It still needs some work because it only works with rank 2 arrays, but it should be fine for the example you posted.

Now you can call your calculate function like this:

```
Calculate(myArray.Slice(0));
```

Note that due to the way IEnumerable and the yield statement work the for loop in the code I posted is essentially free.  It won't run until you actually iterate the items in your Calculate method, and even there runs in a "just-in-time" fashion so that the whole algorithm remains O(n).

It gets even more interesting when you share what your Calculate method is doing.  You might be able to express it as a simple Aggregate + lambda expression.  For example, let's say your calculate method returned the number of items > 5:

```
myArray.Slice(0).Count(x => x > 5);
```

Or say it summed all the items:

```
myArray.Slice().Sum();
```

Comment: This is certainly a better solution if the problem calls for a real multidimensional array and not a jagged one.

Answer (score 4):

A jagged array works the way you want:

```
double[][] jaggedArray = new double[][100];
for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; ++i)
    jaggedArray[i] = new double[100];

myFunction(jaggedArray[0]);
```

You can have different sizes for each array in this way.

Comment: Is there a way I can initialize my jagged array without using a for ? I mean something like : double[][] jaggedArray = new double[100][100]; ?

Comment: No, essentially, you are building an array of `double[]` objects. Those objects are totally unrelated to the original array.

Answer (score 0):

A jagged array would let you split out the first array!

Answer (score 0):

The Slice() method given above will get you a single row from your array, which seems to match the sample given in your question.

However, if you want a one dimensional array that contains **all** the elements in the rectangular array, you can use something like this, which is also O(n).

```
public static T[] Flatten<T>(this T[,] array) 
  where T : struct
{      
  int size = Marshal.SizeOf(array[0, 0]);
  int totalSize = Buffer.ByteLength(array);
  T[] result = new T[totalSize / size];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, result, 0, totalSize);
  return result;      
}
```